# Umbraco 8.17 How to get page id of a different page?

Tags: umbraco8

I needed to get to a different page if certain conditions were meet within my SurfaceController. If you have the page ID of the page you need to get to this is ease. The problem was I did not want to hard code a page id in the action method in the controller. I had a lot of problems trying to figure it out, so I thought I would provide my solution in case someone else is having the same issue.

```
                int homePageID = 0;
                try
                {
                    homePageID = Umbraco.ContentAtXPath("//home").FirstOrDefault().Id;
                }
                catch(Exception e) { }
                if(homePageID > 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToUmbracoPage(homePageID);
                }
                else
                {
                    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
                }
```

Note that for this line "homePageID = Umbraco.ContentAtXPath("//home").FirstOrDefault().Id;" you use the page alias not the page name.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int homePageID = 0;

try
{
    homePageID = Umbraco.ContentAtXPath("//home").FirstOrDefault().Id;
}
catch(Exception e) { }
if(homePageID > 0)
{
    return RedirectToUmbracoPage(homePageID);
}
else
{
    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).